# Open PDF in React with correct title

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to open a PDF in new tab in React JS. The code is attached below. The issue I am having is that my pdf file is having its name altered in the new tab. The tab header becomes `sampe.e72672.pdf`. I do I just make it sample? Also how do I define a hard coded URL for the new tab?

```
import React from "react";
import Resume from "../static/sample.pdf";

  return (
    <div className="MainLandingContainer">
      <div className="ResumeContainer">
        <Button variant="primary" target="_blank" href={Resume}>
          Resume
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Landing;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we can't change the `baseURL` of a window without reloading to a new URL. But we can change the path using `history.pushState`. Here is a solution which is working in Mozilla and Chrome.

```
import React from "react";
import Resume from "./Sample.pdf";

const Landing = () => {
  const openPDF = () => {
    const pdfWindow = window.open("test");
    const title     = "My PDF";
    const URI       = "test/test";
    const html      = `
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>${title}</title>
        </head>
        <body style="margin:0">
          <embed width="100%" height="100%" src=${Resume} type="application/pdf">
        </body>
      </html>
    `;

    pdfWindow.document.write(html);
    pdfWindow.document.close();
    pdfWindow.history.pushState(null, null, URI);
  };

  return (
    <div className="MainLandingContainer">
      <div className="ResumeContainer">
        <button variant="primary" target="_blank" onClick={openPDF}>
          Resume
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Landing;
```

You can find the codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-rosalind-mrv0p?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you @Niyas !